# MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation how to fix?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

in the shopping cart project, am trying to get the  **total amount** in the cart but my aggregation  method has some problems , how to fix this ?

> > error

```
callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(document));
                             ^
MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Failed to parse number '1,39,999' in $convert with no onError value: Did not consume whole string.
```

> > user_helpers.js   this the aggregation

```
getTotalAmount:(userId)=>{
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
        let total=await db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).aggregate([
            {
                $match:{user:objectId(userId)}
            },
            {
                $unwind:'$products'
            },{
                $project:{
                    item:'$products.item',
                    quantity:'$products.quantity',
                 
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup:{
                    from:collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION,
                    localField:'item',
                    foreignField:'_id',
                    as:'product'
                }
            },
            {
                $project:{
                    item:1,quantity:1,product:{$arrayElemAt:['$product',0]}
                } 
            },
            {
                $group:{ 
                    _id:null, 
                    total:{$sum:{$multiply:[{ $toInt: '$quantity'},{ $toInt: '$product.Price' }]}}  // my assumption , here comes the error
                } 
            }
 
        ]).toArray()
       
        resolve(total.length > 0 ? total[0].total: 0)  // or here
    })
}
```

> > user.js

// GET: view shopping cart contents

```
router.get('/cart',middleware.verifyLogin,async(req,res,next)=>{
   try{
      let user=req.session.user._id;
      let products =await userHelpers.getCartProducts(req.session.user._id)
      let totalValue=0 
      if(products.length>0){   
      totalValue=await userHelpers.getTotalAmount(req.session.user._id)
      let proId=req.params.id
      console.log('proId>>>>>>>>>>',proId);
      }
     
    console.log('products>',products)
      console.log("user...",user);
    res.render('user/cart',{products,user,totalValue,});

}catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
 }
 
})
```

It comes when you click the cart button error is getting ,
how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says itself, your database contains strings like `1,39,999`. When MongoDB tries to convert these to an integer, it fails because of the commas. So, before converting the string to an integer, you should remove all the commas and other non-numeric characters from the string. Like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user: ObjectId("userId433456666666666666")
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$products"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      item: "$products.item",
      quantity: "$products.quantity",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION",
      localField: "item",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "product"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      item: 1,
      quantity: 1,
      product: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$product",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
            $group: {
              _id: null,
              total: {
                $sum: {
                  $multiply: [
                    {
                         $toInt: '$quantity'
                    },
                    {
                      $toInt: {
                        "$replaceAll": {
                          "input": "$product.Price",
                          "find": ",",
                          "replacement": ""
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
    ]).toArray()
```

Here we are using [`$replaceAll`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceAll/) to replace the commas with an empty string.

Comment: yes, got the Cause of error , I inserted the Price is like this  49,990, this comma is the problem

Comment: Cool, try the above query and let me know if it worked.

Comment: when using this code getting error , **MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $replaceAll requires that 'input' be a string, found: 2      
    at Connection.onMessage**

Comment: Is there any need to change here?  in    **$group**

Comment: yes , got it  , am used `"$replaceAll"` only in  `"$product.Price"` now it working fine, thank you so much,  bro.